# Move to next page

Tags: php, jquery, oracle, pagination, jquery-easyui

I'm tring to make a pagination of datagrid with jquery easyui in php. The data are imported correct, sql query is working fine, even the first page looks fine, I can choose the number of the rows on page, the calculation of the pages is fine, but when I want to move from first page  to second one, on the second page it shows me only one row. 
Here is my code:

```
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1; 
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
$offset = ($page-1)*$rows;

$result = array();

$db_con = oci_connect('system', 'password1', 'dashboard');

$sql = "select count(*) from dash_omc_cases c, dash_omc_sap s where c.CASE_ID = s.CASE_ID"; $stid = oci_parse($db_con, $sql); oci_execute($stid);
$row = oci_fetch_row($stid); $result["total"] = $row[0];



 $sql =  select * from (
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by c.CREATION_TIME desc) rn, c.case_id as NGM_ID,   
       s.NE_PRIORITAET as NE_PRIO,
       case substr(s.NE_ID, 2,1)
         when '0' then 'Zentrale'
         when '1' then 'Nord'
         when '2' then 'Nord' 
         when '3' then 'Ost'
         when '4' then 'Ost'
         when '5' then 'Mitte'
         when '6' then 'West'
         when '7' then 'Süd'
         when '8' then 'Mitte'
         when '9' then 'Süd'
         else          'Error'
       end as REGION,         
       c.STATUS_NGM as NGM_STATUS,
       s.AUFTRAG as AUFTRAG,
       s.NE_ID as NE_ID,
       s.STATUS as SAP_STATUS,
       substr(to_timestamp(to_char(Sysdate, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 8,12) as DIFF_BEGINN_SAP_ENDE,
      case trim(s.KATEGORIE)
         when '1' then 'INSLA'
         when '2' then 'OUTSLA'
         else          s.KATEGORIE
       end as SLA,
       to_char(c.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
        as NGM_CREATION_TIME,
       case s.NE_PRIORITAET
         when 'A' then substr(to_char((to_timestamp(to_char((Sysdate + 6/24), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss'), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')), 'dd hh24:mi:ss'),8,12)
         when 'B' then substr(to_char((to_timestamp(to_char((Sysdate + 1), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')), 'dd hh24:mi:ss'), 8,12)
         when 'C' then substr(to_char((to_timestamp(to_char((Sysdate + 1), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')), 'dd hh24:mi:ss'),8,12)
         else          substr(to_char((to_timestamp(to_char((Sysdate + 1), 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(to_char(s.CREATION_TIME, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'yyyy.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss')), 'dd hh24:mi:ss'), 8,12)
        end as TIME_LEFT_OVERRUN,

       c.URSACHE_KURZ as URSACHE_KURZ,
       s.BEARBEITER as BEARBEITER
      from dash_omc_cases c, dash_omc_sap s
      where c.CASE_ID = s.CASE_ID
)where rn between %s and %s order by rn", $offset, $rows);
```

Comment: There is a whole lot going on between a database query and jQuery UI. Since you posted PHP code that mainly consists of a couple of queries, I hope/assume that you already figured out that the problem is in the query? If so, please confirm that and remove jQuery from the question. It's a whole different subject and is noise to the question.

Comment: What are the values for `$offset` and `$rows` when you render the second page? And how many results do you get when you execute the query without the last `where` clause? And what range does `rn` have in that case.